# Virtually Navigating Webpages with Python

Tags: python, bots

I've been using the 'win32api' module with Python to emulate keyboard and mouse controls in order to make simple bots to do little tasks, like spamming my friends on Skype or cheating in flash games.

Now I wanted a way to do something similar, but rather than emulating keyboard commands to play on a webpage, it would send the data to the webpage directly. For example, I may want to make a program that browses a forum searching for times people use a certain key-phrase or key-word, then responds. I could do this by emulating keyboard and mouse commands, but I wouldn't be able to use the computer while it was running, plus it would be extremely difficult to get it to read the words straight off the webpage.

I was wondering if anyone knew of any module that allows you to send simple data to a webpage to do small tasks, such as filling in a form or clicking a hyperlink?
If an example could be provided too, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `mechanize` library - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/

It gives you DOM-level page manipulation (you can select particular forms, fill them in, submit data etc), can navigate/submit forms, handle cookies and do many things and I think this is just what you want - behaving just like typical user.

I used it for my bot to process through facebook OAuth and it did just fine.